# Excel Count if with index match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, index-match

I'm trying count number of values from another sheet into column O which has same system name as column B and more than Zero. Could you please let me know the best way to do this?

Comment: have you tried [`COUNTIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) or [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.  As you can I have added another pic above, I need to count the number of values whose column name matches with the row name in "column B (System Name).

Comment: So if B2 was "HP 5224 (203)", then the result would be 4 (per your screen cap? Is the secon screencap from a different worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer. Posting it so someone can use it.

```
Countif(Index(rangeoflookupvalues,,match(Columnvaluetobematched, rangeofcolumns,0)),">0")
```